# Google protobuf in Linux

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I'm working with protobuf and Linux. Where is its compiler `protoc`? I've downloaded the package from the main site, compiled and installed it successfully but I can't find `protoc` to build my own format file. Where is it?

**UPDATE**
Here is folder where I built protobuf:

```
aclocal.m4        depcomp                       Makefile.in
autogen.sh        editors                       missing
CHANGES.txt       examples                      protobuf-lite.pc
config.guess      generate_descriptor_proto.sh  protobuf-lite.pc.in
config.h          gtest                         protobuf.pc
config.h.in       install-sh                    protobuf.pc.in
config.log        INSTALL.txt                   python
config.status     java                          README.txt
config.sub        libtool                       src
configure         ltmain.sh                     stamp-h1
configure.ac      m4                            vsprojects
CONTRIBUTORS.txt  Makefile
COPYING.txt       Makefile.am
```

There isn't a binary file I need.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's probably installed into `/usr/local/bin`

On Ubuntu at least, you can `apt-get install protobuf-compiler` instead.

From the INSTALL.txt:

> ## Installation Names
>
> By default, 'make install' will install the package's files in
>   '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/local/man', etc.  You can specify an
>   installation prefix other than '/usr/local' by giving 'configure' the
>   option '--prefix=PATH'.

Comment: Yeah... It was in /usr/local/lib. Thank you.

Comment: I kind of suspected that name of package would be protobuf. Are you sure this installs protobuf as well?

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to compile you source code from protobuff (in the root folder):

```
./configure  
make   
make check   
make install
```

Second:

```
echo "/usr/local/lib">>/etc/ld.so.conf  
echo "/usr/lib">>/etc/ld.so.conf    
ldconfig
```

Third:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

Read README.txt in root folder for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are in fact on Ubuntu, then you can also fetch the source package from Debian unstable and rebuild them locally if you want packages that are more current than the last cutoff (which for Ubuntu 9.10 was some time late last summer). That way you end up with .deb packages and you preserve a normal upgrade path (rather than littering /usr/local with one-off installs).

Comment: Answer would be better is you said explicitly how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can find protoc in the path which you set ./configure --prefix=you_path.
When you make install successful, it will general bin, include and lib in that path.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to know it's place.
All you want is to open terminal where your proto file is located and write at terminal

```
protoc -I=. --cpp_out=. filename.proto
```

follow this link for [documentation](https://helpmanual.io/help/protoc/)